# Update Status of TFS Builds with Powershell

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfsbuild

Am using the default template and having a powershell which i intend to change the status of my build based on some conditions.

```
$QueueBuild = $buildServer.QueueBuild($buildServer.GetBuildDefinition($project,$BuildDefName))
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
Write-Host "Build Queued"

$buildServer = $collection.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IBuildServer])
$buildSpec = $buildServer.CreateBuildDetailSpec("$project", $env:TF_BUILD_BUILDDEFINITIONNAME)

$builds = $buildServer.QueryBuilds($buildSpec)
```

I am have logic to check for the deployment status and getting them compared before i intend to change the status.

```
if ($InitialVal -eq $FinalVal)
{
     $builds.Builds[-1].Status = "PartiallySucceeded"
     #-1 will get the previous build - which happens to be the build which i have triggered
}
```

`$builds.Builds[-1].Status` is not getting updated as PartiallySucceeded and the status remain Succeeded.

Any help here would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Is the `.Status` set by a numerical value? Maybe you need to change it to `2` instead of `PartiallySucceeded`? Im sure there is an Enum you could take advantage of in this case but i cant find it.

Comment: Found the enumeration i was looking for [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.buildstatus.aspx). Its called `BuildStatus` and its part of the namespace `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client`

Comment: Did you try calling `Save` on the build?

Comment: I was missing the save. Am able to get this done. Thanks Mike!!